# Hyperbolic distance in the upper half-space

Tags: riemannian-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, geodesic

For the upper half-plane $\mathbb{H}=\{z:\mathrm{Im} z>0\}$, the hyperbolic metric is $\frac{|dz|}{y}$, the hyperbolic geodesics are semicircles and vertical ray and the hyperbolic distance is
$$d_{h}(z,w)= \mathrm{Arccosh}\left(1+ \frac{|z-w|^2}{2 \mathrm{Im}(z) \mathrm{Im}(w)}\right).$$
Now for the upper half-space $\mathbb{H}^{n+1}=\{x=(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_{n+1}):x_{n+1}>0, x_i\in \mathbb{R}, 1\leq i \leq n\}$. I know its hyperbolic metric is $\frac{|dx|}{x_{n+1}}$. What I would like to know is its hyperbolic distance and hyperbolic geodesics. I searched Google and some books of hyperbolic geometry, but I found nothing. Any help or references will be appreciated!

Comment: The intuitive generalization would be $$d_{h}(x,y)=\mathrm{Arccosh}(1+ \frac{|x-y|^2}{2 x_{n+1} y_{n+1} })$$

Comment: The geodesics are semicircles that contain a point $P$ such that $OP$ is orthogonal to the hyperplane spanned by $x_{n+1} = 0$

Comment: Ie. parametrically of the form $$f(a) = r(\cos(a) Y + \sin(a) (0,0,\dots 1))  + C$$ where $|Y| = 1$,  $Y_{n+1} = 0$, $C_{n+1} = 0$

Comment: Did you read Bridson-Haefliger or Ratcliffe's book "Foundations of Hyperbolic Manifolds"?

Comment: @user3257842 Thanks for your hint, I think I understand all of them^_^

Comment: @markvs Thanks for your references, I find what I needed in $\S4.6$.